# What is the expected behaviour of an Intel CPU when dealing with a type larger than its cache line?

Tags: c++, c, caching, cpu, cpu-architecture

Assume that I feed an array `T array[N]` to my CPU, where `T` is a big type, a big `struct`, that is larger than `64` bytes, assuming that `64` bytes is also the size of your cache line in your CPU; my question is: what is supposed to be the observable behaviour ? What I can diagnose ?

Obviously I'm assuming that my `T` and my `array` are both packed and aligned and the data structures involved are optimized as far as their layout and placement in memory is concerned . My main focus is about the case where T > cache line and the technicalities that can explain what happens in this circumstances .

Comment: Well even if your type is bigger than a cache line, the actual machine code will only access your type in 128-bit or smaller accesses.  So it's no different than an array of smaller types, really.

Answer (score 3):

Your CPU doesn't see types, in particular no `struct` types or anything, this is a language specific encapsulation. It only sees accesses to the individual fields that your compiler separates out of this. All these fields are either integers, pointers or floating point at the end, and your CPU knows to handle these efficiently.

Comment: I mentioned `T` for its size, I know that the CPU can only see something that is "addressable" in a really generic way, my point is how to consider this and how the CPU operates in this case; for example a cache line of 64 bytes filled with 63 bytes of data is considered unaligned, and this can possibly lead to some losses in terms of performances, what about this case ? And now that you mentioned it, I would like to also get my eyes on a good source that will explain how my CPU manages unsigned and signed integers, but this is probably OT.

Comment: I am not sure that we understand each other. The compiler is doing all the work for you, for example he ensures that your data is properly aligned inside your `struct` such that you don't have to worry about these things. If you don't need all the fields that you have in the `struct` most of the time, you may in fact spread out your data over more cache lines than necessary for it. But this is not much different of accessing not all elements in array of integers, e.g.

Comment: I get the compiler part, I'm having troubles in picturing what the CPU is doing in this case and based on what protocols. For example an array of data ( "array" meaning any sequence of "hot" data ), is usually split in equal parts based on the size of the cache line, for example an array[N], where N much larger than 64, is divided in chunks of 64 bytes, and fed to the different cores of my multicore CPU, at this point is relatively easy to understand how cache coherency works and why is needed. What kind of protocols are valid in this case where any T doesn't fit a single cache line ?

Comment: It's basically guaranteed that my T will break the cache coherency protocol AFAIK how a CPU works . There are other policies ? other protocols ?

Comment: @user2485710, you seem to have some misconception about either cache coherency, or multithreaded programming. If you wrote your program under some parallel framework please state that in the question, otherwise there's no reason your work would be distributed so. Either way, cache coherency doesn't just break like that.

Comment: @Leeor I don't think so, mostly because of my experience and what I heard from other people and read from other sources; there apparently I failed to communicate the problem. It doesn't matter, I'll try to check other source to find an answer .

Comment: @user2485710, I didn't mean that in a discouraging way, i'll be happy to help if you only provide more context for your problem (how are you parallelizing it for starters). Regardless, cache coherency does not break (otherwise a lot of CPU manufacturers would collapse from the cost of recalls). Your code may produce bogus results in some cases if you do dangerous stuff without protection, but not because the CPU is wrong.